# invalid cruntime parameter _itoa_s

Tags: c++, winapi

I have experienced a strange behavior when using `_itoa_s` and `_ultoa_s` if I try to get a char array from an `DWORD`. The function returns zero(success) and my application continues, but I'm getting an exception window with error code `0xc0000417 (STATUS_INVALID_CRUNTIME_PARAMETER)`.

```
ULONG pid = ProcessHandleToId(hProcess);  
int size = getIntSize(pid);  
char *pidStr = new char[size+1];  
_ultoa_s(pid, pidStr, size+1, 10);  
//do sth with pidStr...
delete[] (pidStr);`
```

`ProcessHandleToId` returns the `PID (DWORD)` for a given `ProcessHandle`.

`getIntSize` returns the number of numbers to the corresponding `int/char` array (5555 => 4).

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but you should use `delete[]`.

Comment: "..but I'm getting an exception.." - When? Your code seems to be correct, btw.

Comment: i can compile my code and my application seems 2 run. To give a little bit more background information: this code is part of a callback routine called when NtTerminateProcess is called. I need the processid of the terminated process. When i run my app everytime ultoa_s is called my application is interrupted and i get the 0xc000417 exception blabla window.... BUT the function returns with 0 (success) and the correct value (pid) is stored in pidStr ... it's driving me crazy!
I use the same code in another routine and it works without any problems.

Comment: If you're in C++, why not just use a stringstream to convert the PID to a string?

Comment: sstream method results in pid being 0 everytime :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the safe CRT functions will abort your program with status code 0xc0000417 when they detect a problem.  However, they will do this *immediately*, the function will *not* return.

Which means that you are looking at the wrong source code for this problem.  It isn't the _ultoa_s() call that's bombing your program.  It's another function call, somewhere else in your code.  I can't help you find it of course.  But the debugger should give you a good idea, look at the call stack when it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I just compiled your code and it runs fine. The int to string conversion is correct. I assume you bump into security issues due to missing permission when trying to access process handles you don't own.

Comment: As i mentioned before: the funny thing is, _ultoa_s returns with success and even gives me the correct char-array (pid as string) after closing the exception window. I'm using the same code in another part of my Dll and it work's without any problems.