# Unexpected Program exit with Code 0xC0000417 (Invalid C-Runtime Parameter)

Tags: c++, c, debugging, mfc, visual-studio-2013

After upgrading a big project to Visual Studio 2013, the program cased a crash (Program stopped working) on a normal computer.

Now when I debug this program in Visual Studio 2013, I don't see anything, except of the last message: "The program '[3948] Server.exe' has exited with code -1073740777 (0xc0000417)."

The Code is defined in "ntstatus.h" as "Invalid C-Runtime Parameter"

That's at least more, than just the "Program Stopped Working" message, I guess.

Is there any way to catch this error? As the project is overly big, and some Libraries could have changed, I have no overview over all the parameter calls in this program.

So I'm looking for a way to globally catch this error in my program in order to find out the invalid Parameter call. The program is also MFC Dialog based and does not contain a "main" method, why I couldn't find a way to globally use "_set_invalid_parameter_handler" which seems to be a C method, and not object orientatet at all.

Thank you for any help! :)

Comment: "After upgrading a big project to Visual Studio 2013..." **from**... ? It makes a difference, as the symptoms you're describing sound like an overrun in one of the "safe" functions (`strcpy_s`, `sprintf_s`, etc). While upgrading your project, how many of those did you likewise upgrade to appease the warning barrage that ensued shortly thereafter? An example of the panic that shuts down your process is [**this question and answers**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467444/invalid-cruntime-parameter-itoa-s). Worth a read.

Comment: To globally catch an exception, use [SetUnhandledExceptionFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680634.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot @WhozCraig this was it!
I updated some strncpy calls to strncpy_s. After undoing this changes, the program runs fine again! I will research the calls to those strncpy functions now and check how they could be called wrong!

Comment: Eh, I'm struggling the same issue. I have configured MSVC to catch 0xc0000417, but it doesn't :\

Answer (score 0):

There may be much simpler causes, in my case a miscalculated value in _chdrive(), which turned out negative. Without explaining how, and being quite ashamed of this quite stupid bug, the outcome was not an error in _chdrive(), but unexpected program exit with code 0xc0000417 (invalid c runtime parameter), indeed.